# SVG Linear Gradient SVG Background

Tags: javascript, svg, background, linear-gradients

I am trying to use an SVG, which will be dynamically created from JavaScript, as the background image on another SVG.  This works when the fill color of the object is a solid color, but not when I try to use a linear gradient.  Run the code to see an example.  Please help figure how to use the linear gradient!

```js
        const createElement = (tag, attributes) => {
            const element = document.createElement(tag);
            if (attributes) Object.keys(attributes).forEach(key => element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]));
            return element;
        }

        // Create background for first SVG using solid color fill:
        const svg3bg = createElement('svg', { xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', viewBox: '0 0 50 50', width: 50, height: 50 });
        svg3bg.appendChild(createElement('circle', { cx: 25, cy: 25, r: 20, fill: '#00F' }));
        const svg3 = document.getElementById('svg3');
        svg3.style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml,${svg3bg.outerHTML.replace(/\#/g, '%23')}')`; // This does not display unless I replace the # signs with a hex code.
        svg3.style.backgroundColor = 'palegreen';

        // Create background for second SVG using linear gradient fill:
        const svg4bg = createElement('svg', { xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', viewBox: '0 0 50 50', width: 50, height: 50 });
        const lg4 = svg4bg.appendChild(createElement('linearGradient', { id: "lg4" }))
        lg4.appendChild(createElement('stop', { offset: "0%", 'stop-color': '#d67ef5' }))
        lg4.appendChild(createElement('stop', { offset: "50%", 'stop-color': '#2b78ba' }))
        lg4.appendChild(createElement('stop', { offset: "100%", 'stop-color': '#4d79a9' }))
        svg4bg.appendChild(createElement('circle', { cx: 25, cy: 25, r: 20, fill: 'url(#lg4)' }));
        const svg4 = document.getElementById('svg4');
        svg4.style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml,${svg4bg.outerHTML.replace(/\#/g, '%23')}')`;
        svg4.style.backgroundColor = 'palegreen';
```

```html
    This shows an SVG using another SVG (generated from JavaScript) of blue dots as its background image:
    <div id="div3">
        <svg id="svg3" iewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width: 150; height: 150;">
            <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="stroke: black; fill: none; stroke-width: 4"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div><br>
    When trying to do the same thing with a linear gradient to fill the object instead of a solid color, it does not
    display:
    <div id="div4">
        <svg id="svg4" iewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width: 150; height: 150;">
            <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="stroke: black; fill: none; stroke-width: 4"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div><br>
    This shows what the background image with the linear gradient should look like:
    <div id="div5">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
            <lineargradient id="lg5">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#d67ef5"></stop>
                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2b78ba"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4d79a9"></stop>
            </lineargradient>
            <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#lg5)"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems OK to me once I correct all the typos.

- viewBox is missing a v in some places
- units are missing from CSS sizes where they are mandatory
- use createElementNS to create SVG elements and use an XML serializer rather than HTML serialization to get namespaces in the output.
- while not necessary in this case I've fixed the URI encoding properly rather than using replace

```js
const createElement = (tag, attributes) => {
            const element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
            if (attributes) Object.keys(attributes).forEach(key => element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]));
            return element;
        }

        let s = new XMLSerializer();
        // Create background for first SVG using solid color fill:
        const svg3bg = createElement('svg', { viewBox: '0 0 50 50', width: 50, height: 50 });
        svg3bg.appendChild(createElement('circle', { cx: 25, cy: 25, r: 20, fill: '#00F' }));
        const svg3 = document.getElementById('svg3');
        svg3.style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(s.serializeToString(svg3bg))}')`;
        svg3.style.backgroundColor = 'palegreen';

        // Create background for second SVG using linear gradient fill:
        const svg4bg = createElement('svg', { viewBox: '0 0 50 50', width: 50, height: 50 });
        const lg4 = svg4bg.appendChild(createElement('linearGradient', { id: "lg4" }))
        lg4.appendChild(createElement('stop', { offset: "0%", 'stop-color': '#d67ef5' }))
        lg4.appendChild(createElement('stop', { offset: "50%", 'stop-color': '#2b78ba' }))
        lg4.appendChild(createElement('stop', { offset: "100%", 'stop-color': '#4d79a9' }))
        svg4bg.appendChild(createElement('circle', { cx: 25, cy: 25, r: 20, fill: 'url(#lg4)' }));
        const svg4 = document.getElementById('svg4');
        svg4.style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(s.serializeToString(svg4bg))}')`;
        svg4.style.backgroundColor = 'palegreen';
```

```html
This shows an SVG using another SVG (generated from JavaScript) of blue dots as its background image:
    <div id="div3">
        <svg id="svg3" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
            <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="stroke: black; fill: none; stroke-width: 4"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div><br>
    When trying to do the same thing with a linear gradient to fill the object instead of a solid color, it does not
    display:
    <div id="div4">
        <svg id="svg4" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
            <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="stroke: black; fill: none; stroke-width: 4"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div><br>
    This shows what the background image with the linear gradient should look like:
    <div id="div5">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
            <linearGradient id="lg5">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#d67ef5"></stop>
                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2b78ba"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4d79a9"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#lg5)"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Interestingly, I was trying createElementNS, but when I was also using outerHTML, it was not including the xmlns attribute in the output.  Then also when using createElementNS, it would not allow me to add the xmlns attribute using setAttribute or setAttributeNS.  So that is why I switched to createElement, so I could just add the xmlns attribute manually.  But I see now, when using createElementNS in conjunction with encodeURIComponent instead of outerHTML, the xmlns attribute is included.  Ergo, encodeURIComponent is indeed part of the solution, along with using createElementNS.

Comment: Minor note: If you don't require the ``appendChild( element )`` **return** value. Then dump all those statements and use ``append``, it takes **multiple** arguments (or spread an Array) See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: @AdamSassano really its serializeToString that preserves the namespace and replaces outerHTML. encodeURIComponent replaces the replace function.